# Why does wxPython panel masks key down event?

Tags: python, event-handling, wxpython, panel

Can anyone explain why adding a panel hides the left and right arrow keys?

```
import wx
class AForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Press Key")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onKeyPress)
        self.Show()
    def onKeyPress(self, event):
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        print keycode
app = wx.App()
form = AForm()
app.MainLoop()
```

If I remove the panel it works!  But, the panel seems to be necessary to get the form to look like a Windows application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are actually two use you could go about this.

either you call the [wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/KeyEvent.html#keyevent) instead of `wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN` on the panel, (though this way the event is propagated all the way to the to parent window (the frame) , instead of being handled strictly by the panel, so i think it would be better for you to go with the second option):

```
panel.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.onKeyPress)
```

or you define in the the panel constructor that it `wx.WANTS_CHARS` as mentioned in the [wxpython window documentation](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html) to allow it to catch those aditional chars like so:

```
panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, style= wx.WANTS_CHARS)
panel.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.onKeyPress)
```

Comment: I thought I tried these but you are right, it does work.  I also found something strange!  If you press the Alt key, the left and right arrows are detected with my problem code.  This made me think of using an event list!